# Google Sites: Google or Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, openid, google-classic-sites

I would like to use Google Sites to create a membership web site, where somebody could come to the public landing page and then sign in with Google or Facebook (e.g. using OpenID) and then get access to protected pages.

Are there any open-source applications or tutorials or libraries which can help make this possible? If not, can anybody explain how to do this?

Comment: Similar question on SO might be helpful [How to add social login services...to my website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235735/how-to-add-social-login-services-from-google-facebook-yahoo-etc-to-my-website)

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenID Foundation](https://openid.net/developers/) has lots of information.

Many common CMS platforms, like [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/) and [Magento](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/social-login-7335.html), have their own plugins already built.

If you just want to use Google, you visit their [Federated Login for Google Account Users](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) page. For just Facebook, visit [Facebook Login for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/).

Answer (score 0):

OpenID Wiki has a page of [Libraries](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries) many of which have decent documentation, that all help with implementing OpenID Identity Server on your own site.